# Can I get eyes to be included in ARSCNFaceGeometry (to get 3D pupil coordinates from VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D)?

Tags: swift, ios9, scenekit, arkit

I'm attempting to perform 3D feature detection using ARKit and SceneKit on an iPhone X, using Vision to detect facial landmarks. I then use `ARSCNView.hitTest` to cast the 2D face landmark against the face topology obtained with `ARSCNFaceGeometry`. This works great but I'm having trouble with the pupils. It's very hard to get hit test results with the pupils, and I'm assuming this is because the face geometry has gaps where the eyes are. Is there a way to get an accurate z-value from the `leftPupil` and `rightPupil` `VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D` coordinates by adding eyes to the face geometry to perform a `hitTest`, for example?

My hacky idea currently is to use the z values of the surrounding `eye` landmarks and use that value to `unproject` the 2D pupils into the scene, but of course this isn't as accurate as I would like it to be. Any help or any other ideas would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `fillMesh: true` when you create the `ARSCNFaceGeometry` it won't leave an empty gap for the eyes and mouth.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnfacegeometry/2928202-init

Comment: Wow thanks so much!! I switched to trying to use the AVDepthData approach to get ears too, which presents other obstacles. But at least now I can switch back to hit testing for the main face geometry if I need to.